# API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/callback/credentials, this may result in stalled requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, postman, next-auth

When i try to login using `Talend API Tester`, getting this into terminal:

> `API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/callback/credentials, this may result in stalled requests.`

**Besides, here is the image of Request:**

[image]

I followed this: [Next-Auth.js -> Rest API](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api)

---

Why I'm getting this kind of response & warning?

Below is the `[..nextauth.js]` **file's code**. What's wrong with my code?

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'

const options = {
    providers: [
        Providers.Credentials({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "something@example.com" },
                password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
              },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const {email, password} = credentials
                const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { email, password } })
                console.log(user);
            
                // If no error and we have user data, return it
                if (user) {
                return user
                }
                // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
                return null
          }
        })
      ]
}

export default async function handle(req, res) {
    console.log('I see');
    NextAuth(req, res, options) 
}
```

**Note:** Actually I don't want to send `csrfToken` in the body. Only `email` & `password` to the endpoint. Please have a look into my this question [How to do authentication using NextAuth.js without login page (using postman)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68320519/how-to-do-authentication-using-nextauth-js-without-login-page-using-postman)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return` before your `NextAuth` call: `return NextAuth(req, res, options)`?

Comment: Ya. Hmm same issue: `Sorry, the Chrome API does not allow to get a response body for redirect.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"json": true` in the body.
Something like this:

```
{
  "csrfToken": YOUR_TOKEN,
  "username": YOUR_USERNAME,
  "password": YOUR_PASSWORD,
  "json": true
}
```